# Asp.Net Core class not passing data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

In asp.net core 2.1 Identity I am using a class to move the login name from ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs and Login.cshtml to save them to another table via a class AddUserToStudentTable.

EDIT - I have got the terminology of DTO wrong, but consider it just a class that pushes data around. I just used the wrong naming convention.

The class is

```
public class StudentNameDTO : IStudentNameDTO
{
    public string StudentGoogleNameLogin { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool IsExternal { get; set; } = false;
}
```

The Startup is using AddSingleton but I have also tried AddTransient, with no difference.

```
services.AddSingleton<IStudentNameDTO, StudentNameDTO>();
```

And I am using the usual Constructor injection automatically done with wonderful VS 2017

Yet when passing data I always get an error of

> evaluation of method () calls into native method system System.Environment.FailFast().

and it all crashes down with

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   ASPNZBat.Business.AddUserToStudentTable.AddUserToStudent(string Email) in AddUserToStudentTable.cs + if (_studentNameDTO.IsExternal == true) ASPNZBat.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.ExternalLoginModel.OnGetCallbackAsync(string returnUrl, string remoteError) in ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs + _addUserToStudentTable.AddUserToStudent(Email);

I have tried using AddTransient and AddScope as well in the startup, but no difference. Having worked on it for hours I am starting to doubt my ability to program....

Note that when there is data passing through it works OK. But when there is no data - null - instead of working with it it just crashes. I even wrapped it in a boolean to see if I could catch the output with that but it crashed at the boolean as well.

Data going in

```
if (info.Principal.Identity.Name != null)
{
    _studentNameDTO.IsExternal = true;
    _studentNameDTO.StudentGoogleNameLogin = info.Principal.Identity.Name;

    string Email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);

    _addUserToStudentTable.AddUserToStudent(Email);
}
```

Data coming out

```
string StudentName = string.Empty;
if (_studentNameDTO.IsExternal == true)
{
    StudentName = _studentNameDTO.StudentGoogleNameLogin;
}
```

There is something about passing null data that it doesn't like and I don't understand.

Here is the github acc for it  https://github.com/Netchicken/ASPNZBatV2/tree/master/ASPNZBat

Comment: Why are you registering a DTO in dependency injection?

Comment: Thats a good question. How else should I do it?

Comment: How do you pass the data ? How to reproduce this error? Also, it make no sense to  inject the DTO as an  singleton.

Comment: I am passing data like this  _studentNameDTO.StudentGoogleNameLogin = info.Principal.Identity.Name;  just as you would normally, It works when there IS data, but when there is no name instead of passing null and being happy it crashes as above. Maybe there is another way to reference  the DTO instead of DI that might make it work. I am using a singleton as the name will be unchanged during the lifetime of the site being open. One person logs in only.

Comment: why your dto has interface? Data Transfer Objects is a way of transfering data. also, they dont have anything with services. your service registration doesn't mean anything.

Comment: I suggest you to read some tutorial to clear your misunderstandings

Comment: Simonare, DTO or no DTO its still just a class and the instantiation of it should still work, shouldn't it? If I just said "Hey I have a class named DTO and its registered with DI but it doesn't work" , wouldn'tt it be the same.Its the error I want to solve, the semantics are something I can learn but is it the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've got a case of *Over-Dependency Injection*.

> **Aside**: You almost certainly don't want to be using [`AddSingleton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddSingleton__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Func_System_IServiceProvider___0__) here, a singleton is something that you want your application to have *no more than one instance of* during its execution. In this instance that would mean that if you had two users logging (or whatever the process is here) in at the same time they would both share the same instance of `StudentNameDTO`.

Based on the code in [AddUserToStudentTable.cs](https://github.com/Netchicken/ASPNZBatV2/blob/master/ASPNZBat/Business/AddUserToStudentTable.cs) the reason you're seeing a `NullReferenceException` is that there's nothing here that assigns to `_studentNameDTO` prior to it being used. It's not being injected anywhere, nor is it being passed into the class anywhere, it's declared `private` so isn't accessible from outside the class and is only **read** from on lines 36 and 38.

That said, not everything in your code needs, or should, be instantiated via Dependency Injection. Your `StudentNameDTO` isn't something the class *depends* on, it's something it consumes / modifies. From a cursory look at your code, it looks like the place that obtains all the data that's stored into `StudentNameDTO` is in `ExternalLoginModel.OnGetCallbackAsync` so this is where you should `var studentNameDto = new StudentNameDTO()` before calling `AddUserToStudent` and *passing the instance of `StudentNameDTO` into the method*, e.g. (line 97 onwards):

```
if (info.Principal.Identity.Name != null)
{
    var studentNameDto = new StudentNameDTO
    {
        IsExternal = true,
        _studentNameDTO.StudentGoogleNameLogin = info.Principal.Identity.Name
    };

    string Email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);

    _addUserToStudentTable.AddUserToStudent(studentNameDto, Email);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for those comments and help! I hadn't realised that singleton would be like that. I'll change that as well.  So If I var studentNameDto = new StudentNameDTO() at the input end, and DI it at the output end, it still sees it as the same object and not another instantiation of StudentNameDTO? I'll try that and see how it goes. I also might just pass in the method signature with name and email as parameters and bypass the StudentNameDTO totally :-) Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help! :) Re: Singleton - the clue's in the name *SINGLE*ton, there will only ever be one instance of the class :-) You shouldn't use DI for classes that (I'm simplifying a bit here) just hold data, but for classes that do stuff to classes that just hold data. Hopefully that makes a modicum of sense? :)